Trouble Integrating Zoom SDK in React Native Expo: 'isChatDisabled' Error

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'isChatDisabled' of null, js engine: hermes
//
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isChatDisabled' of null, js engine: hermes
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:


Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called. js engine: hermes

i tried build an video calling application using React native expo with zoom sdk. but it is not working it causes some error called isChatDisabled and i don't what to do, give me a solution for it.
Is zoom ok for building app for P2P communication? or should i go with zegocloud?
I need code for building an video calling application on React native expo
